# What does `awk '{printf("%5.3f,\n", $2)}'` do?

Tags: awk

```
grep "variable1=" $file | awk '{printf("%5.3f,\n", $2)}' > .rpt_variable1
```

My Questions:

1. What does the number 5 in '%5.3f" does?
2. What is the significance of $2?
3. What does the 'awk' command do exactly?

Comment: As usual, the thing to do is to read the awk man page: `man awk` to get an idea of what it does. Then you can read the manual: `info awk` which describes everything in detail. While doing that,  you experiment and get some experience. If you are still up for more info, read the [awk book](https://www.amazon.com/AWK-Programming-Language-Alfred-Aho/dp/020107981X) (by Aho, Weinberger and Kernighan - did you wonder what awk stands for?)

Answer (score 1):

Awk is a program that will scan through a file line by line, find specified strings, and change them (if desired). This entire command is going to look through some file ($file) to find lines with 'variable1=' in them. This is the grep part.

In this case, Awk is looking through those lines for the second field ($2). It is then going to output the value of field 2 in the format of nnnnn.nn (n being a single digit) into the file .rpt_variable1. This looks like a currency format, so field 2 is probably a dollar value. The 5 means it will print the 'dollar' portion as 5 digits (ex. 12500 for $12,500 or 00543 for $543). The 2 in 5.2 means it will print what is after the decimal out to two places, which is normal for cents.

Comment: Not quite (at least on GNU awk): the 5 is a field width, not the number of digits in the whole-number portion of the value; and the number will be padded with spaces on the left, not with 0, if the width is smaller than 5 (although that will be difficult in this case: `%5.3f` means three digits after the decimal point and the decimal point itself is a fourth character, so even a single digit whole-number part will fill the available space. It will be easier to see what's going on if the format is changed to `%10.3f`). For padding with 0, use `%05.3f`.

Comment: You're write. I didn't test this out until after I answered. My tests were not padding out to 5 digits to the left, like they do to the right, which I did not expect. So I guess 5 is the minimum field width, because 123.1 yields 123.10 (6 digits). Anyway, thanks for the correction.

Comment: The grep is not needed. awk does pattern matches itself rather well. Also, I am surprised it works without declaring "=" as a Field Separator -- it must be relying on there being whitespace after the = and before the number. You might have posted a few lines of input.